# <xsl:copy-of> does not preserve XML tags

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

Using `Saxon HE 11.4`, I'm trying to simply copy some text and preserve XML tags inside of that text. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6199958/4934534) and many others tell me that simply using `<xsl:copy-of>` is enough. But it doesn't work in my case, `<xsl:copy-of>` removes all XML tags. Why?

Input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
   <card>
      <k>а</k>
      <body>
         <meaning>
            <trn>возглас удивления</trn>
            <trn>вопрос с оттенком удивления или неудовольствия</trn>            
         </meaning>
      </body>
   </card>
</root>
```

XSLT file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:character-map name="escape-square-brackets">
    <xsl:output-character character="[" string="\["/>
    <xsl:output-character character="]" string="\]"/>
  </xsl:character-map>
  
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-16le" byte-order-mark="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:result-document href="/Users/xinatanil/Desktop/compiling stuff/abbyy_udahin_kg_ru.dsl" method="text">
      <xsl:text>#NAME "Кыргызско-русский словарь"</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>#INDEX_LANGUAGE "Russian"</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>#CONTENTS_LANGUAGE "Russian"</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      
      <root>
        <xsl:for-each select="card">
          <xsl:value-of select="k"/>
          <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
          
          <xsl:for-each select="body/meaning/*">
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>            
            <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>            
          </xsl:for-each>
          
          <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </root>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected output

```
#NAME "Кыргызско-русский словарь"
#INDEX_LANGUAGE "Russian"
#CONTENTS_LANGUAGE "Russian"
а
 <trn>возглас удивления</trn>
 <trn>вопрос с оттенком удивления или неудовольствия</trn>
```

Output that I currently get

```
#NAME "Кыргызско-русский словарь"
#INDEX_LANGUAGE "Russian"
#CONTENTS_LANGUAGE "Russian"

а
 возглас удивления
 вопрос с оттенком удивления или неудовольствия
```

Comment: You have numerous issues beside the output method (which you should have in only place). Please reduce your example code to minimum - see: [mcve].

Comment: I have listed some of your mistakes, but this is not how it's supposed to work. A question should focus on one problem only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by changing the main output method to xml and removing it from the `xsl:result-document` element.

Next, if you want copy the already selected elements that are children of `meaning`, you need to change:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="."/>
```

Otherwise you're copying the child nodes of those elements.

And you probably want to remove the `root` wrapper.

And you will also want to suppress the XML declaration.

Comment: Thank you! Forgot to remove "text" from `<xsl:result-document>`

Comment: You should remove the `method` attribute from `xsl:result-document` altogether. You only need it if you want to override the  `method` attribute of `xsl:output`.

Answer (score 1):

You have used `text` as your `xsl:output method`, that way you don't get the copy of element nodes, just the text nodes. So use e.g. `<xsl:output method="xml"/>` if your target format is XML and not plain text.

Comment: Thank you! That explains probably a lot of issues that I had 

Comment: Okay, my excitement was too soon. The output is still the same ((. Any idea why?

Comment: @xinatanil, you have edited the code and now it selects only text nodes.

Comment: I edited the code but the main culprit was in removing "text" from `<xsl:result-document>` besides `<xsl:output method>`. Thank you very much!

Comment: @MartinHonnen Is it just me, or is https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ broken for good?

Comment: @michael.hor257k, the users have managed to fill up the 6 GB of database quota I had available and I have not managed to make a decision on how to proceed and then implement it, my initial plan was to change the site to allow read only access to existing fiddles, later I have toyed with the idea to somehow play T-SQL DBA and find/eliminate "garbage" in the 6 GB of fiddles but that is not a role I am used to and good at. So in the moment it is up in the air on how to proceed, fiddling without db storage can be done with https://xsltfiddle-beta.liberty-development.net/.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, in case if you are using SQL Server, its 2022 version introduced high level of compression for the XML type columns.

Comment: Thanks. I am afraid I don't have any useful advice. It's just a pity there's currently no way to accompany an answer with a demo.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, consider to add your thoughts or support to my feature request https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422045/feature-request-to-allow-executable-xslt-code-snippets.

Comment: I did. Although it would not have the advantage of selecting the specific processor, it would still be a great help.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, https://xsltfiddle-beta.liberty-development.net/ is up again after I freed up space in the db by removing what appeared to be duplicated revisions.

Comment: You mean the original https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/? Great news, let's hope it lasts for long.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, yes, sorry, managed to post the wrong link, but yes, the original fiddle  is up again.